# CSS layout fails when web page is hosted

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with a CSS layout. Locally everything works fine. The layout is correctly generated in Chrome & IE. However, when the same page is hosted, it's completely in disorder in IE.

To summarize :

**Locally :** file:///C:/website/index.htm

- Chrome : Ok !
- IE 10 : Ok !

**Hosted :** http://www.website.com/index.htm

- Chrome : Ok !
- IE 10: **NOk** !

Does anyone have an idea on the problem ?

Example of code wich works locally but not online :

**CSS**

```
.headerleft {
   float: left; 
   width: 246;
   height: 56;
   background-image:url(images/Logo_2.png);     
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class = "headerleft">      
</div>
```

**StyleSheet link**

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Here for example, the div size is null and no background image is displayed.

Comment: Nope, not without your HTML....

Comment: What version of IE - same version locally and when hosted? What specifically doesn't work? Screen shots or examples would be helpful!

Comment: How do you link to your stylesheet??? Show us some code please.

Comment: Post edited. I added some code.

Comment: If you check the `net` tab in `Firebug`, or `Chrome` developer tools, does everything load? any 404s?

Comment: @drew_w the version of IE doesn't depend on whether the page is hosted or not. Does it ? It's the same IE version I use, I just change the adress from locally to the website.

Comment: @NickR No 404s, everything is perfect online on chrome

Comment: Is this wordpress? You may be colliding with another style.css file.

Comment: @fred02138 not at all, it's a simple web site, completely empty. Only two files index.htm et syle.css (and the images)

Comment: Is IE using compatibility mode when local?

Comment: Your missing **px** on your `.headerleft` - `width` and `height` _style_ so -> `width: 246px;height: 56px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your css. Do not delete anything. See if this makes the image load in IE9.

```
background: url('/images/Logo_2.png');
```

Also if you want it to not repeat add

```
background: url('/images/Logo_2.png') no-repeat;
```

I also must add your question is a little confusing. The link you have added appears to send me to website builders main page.

a few problems you might be having.

1. The link you provided has an extension of .htm not .html for some reason.
   Changing this in the browser does not help.
2. You might be confusing the link to view your page with the link to the main site your using to create it.
3. You could have changed the setting in your htaccess file on server to load a page with a different file extension.

If these steps do not help, please provide more information and I will do my best to assist you.

If your noticing erratic behavior from your divs after floats a clearfix might help this. This is done by clearing your floats.

```
clear: both;
```

This is how you clear floats:

read this to help you understand:
http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Here is and example of code:

create a class in your css

```
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
* html .clearfix             { zoom: 1; } /* IE6 */
*:first-child+html .clearfix { zoom: 1; } /* IE7 */
```

Now you add the clear fix to your html

```
<div style="float: left;" class="clearfix">Sidebar</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. the backgroung property doesn't change anything. The link shown is not expected to send you anywhere, it's just an example :). There is no confusion between the page visited using the link and the page created. It's absolutely the same

Comment: What's is strange though, is that the same IE 10 opens the page correctly when it's in my hard drive, but fails when it's online.

Comment: I changed the extension to html but the problem still persists.

Comment: Is it just the background img that is not showing up correctly?

Comment: Could this be a clear fix problem because you are not clearing your floats?

Comment: how to clear the floats please ?

Comment: I edited my answer and added a explanation and tutorial to clearing floats at the bottom.